# Splash Screen Not Showing Up?

Tags: 10.04, startup, plymouth

When I boot up Ubuntu, all I get is a little blinking underscore at the top left side of my screen. I am using splash screen manager and activated a picture to start at boot up, but it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 3):

Try these two commands:

```
sudo echo FRAMEBUFFER=y > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Download StartUp-Manager from the Ubuntu Software Store. You can specify that you want splash screen in that program, if it isn't already enabled.

Comment: I don't think startup-manager affects plymouth since 10.04, it's built for usplash.